# How to interrupt a blocking system call function from a signal handler in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, system-calls, blocking, signal-handling

I have a thread being generated from the main one which has basically an infinite loop with a system blocking function: something like:

```
def run(self):
    global EXIT
    while not EXIT:
        data = self.conn.recv(1024)
        ...
```

I have defined a signal handler for `SIGINT`

```
def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    global EXIT, threads
    if (signum == 2):#defensive
        print("Called SIGINT")
        EXIT = True
```

Being the signal catched by the main thread, it interrupts the main thread. However the other thread is stuck on the blocking function: is there a way to interrupt a system call blocking function in python so that exiting from this function?

I do not want to stop the process directly how `SIGINT` normally does but I would like just to interrupt `recv` so that the condition of while is not true anymore and I can do other stuff before exiting.

Comment: This may help you [https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/how-to-catch-kill-events-with-python/](https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/how-to-catch-kill-events-with-python/)